# Using Navigator with a bottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

What's the correct way of setting up `navigation` architecture named routes while using a bottomNavigationBar?

Here's my current setup but I feel there's a better way of doing it:

**main.dart:**

```dart
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: settings,
              builder: (context) {
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case NamedRoutes.splashScreen:
                    return SplashScreen();
                  case NamedRoutes.login:
                    return LoginPage();
                  case NamedRoutes.mainApp:
                    return NavigatorSetup();
                  default:
                    throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
                }
              });
```

**navigatorSetup.dart:**

```dart
IndexedStack(
          index: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context).selectedViewIndex,
          children: [FirstMain(), SecondMain(), ThirdMain(), FourthMain()],
        ), bottomNavigationBar...
```

in each **main files** there is the following setup

```dart
class FirstMain extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context).homeKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
              case NamedRoutes.mainPage:
                return MainPage();
              case NamedRoutes.singleMainPage:
                return SingleMainPage();
              default:
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then my **routes provider** looks like this:

```dart
class RoutesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedViewIndex = 0;
  get selectedViewIndex => _selectedViewIndex;
  set selectedViewIndex(int newIndex) {
    _selectedViewIndex = newIndex;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  GlobalKey _mainKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  GlobalKey _homeKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _secondKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _thirdKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _fourthKey = GlobalKey();

  get mainKey => _mainKey;
  get homeKey => _homeKey;
  get secondKey => _secondKey;
  get thirdKey => _thirdKey;
  get fourthKey => _fourthKey;
}
```

The way I'm currently changing routes when on another page of the indexedStack

```dart
final RoutesProvider routesProvider = Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false);
  final GlobalKey thirdKey = routesProvider.thirdKey;
  routesProvider.selectedViewIndex = 2;
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(thirdKey.currentContext, NamedRoutes.third);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The better way to navigate**
Creating a route_generator

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:routing_prep/main.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstPage());
      case SecondPage.routeName:
        // Validation of correct data type
        if (args is String) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => SecondPage(
                  data: args,
                ),
          );
        }
        // If args is not of the correct type, return an error page.
        // You can also throw an exception while in development.
        return _errorRoute();
      default:
        // If there is no such named route in the switch statement, e.g. /third
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Error'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

As you can see, you've moved from having bits of routing logic everywhere around your codebase, to a single place for this logic - in the RouteGenerator. Now, the only navigation code which will remain in your widgets will be the one pushing named routes with a navigator.

Before you can run and test the app, there's still a bit of a setup to do for this RouteGenerator to function.

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      // Initially display FirstPage
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go to second'),
              onPressed: () {
                // Pushing a named route
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                  SecondPage.routeName,
                  arguments: 'Hello there from the first page!',
                );
              },
            )
      ...
  }
}



class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
      static const routeName = "/second";
      // This is a String for the sake of an example.
      // You can use any type you want.
      final String data;
    
      SecondPage({
        Key key,
        @required this.data,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Routing App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Second Page',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                ),
                Text(
                  data,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the bottomNav bar in ur example?

Comment: You don't need to use Navigator if you want to move between the same level on the screen just use Bottom tab bar and put the screens inside children.
see the example it may help you
[link](https://github.com/y-alkhateeb/flutter_tdd_template/blob/master/lib/feature/home/screen/bottom_tab_bar.dart)